# Reading in a Data Set with Columns of Unequal Length in R

Tags: r, reshape, read.table

I have a number of data sets given in the following format:

```
Station number: 505
Location:       Sundarijal                                                        Latitude: 27 46 30
River:          Bagmati River                                                     Longitude: 85 25 40

Year:           1963

                                Mean daily discharge in m3/s
                                ============================

Day     Jan.   Feb.   Mar.   Apr.   May    Jun.   Jul.   Aug.   Sep.   Oct.   Nov.   Dec.   
 01    0.250  0.190  0.100  0.100  0.310  0.160  0.900   4.90   4.86   1.50  0.710  0.400
 02    0.250  0.160  0.130  0.130  0.250  0.160  0.900   4.78   5.01   1.68  0.710  0.400
 03    0.250  0.160  0.220  0.130  0.220  0.600  0.700   4.90   6.00   1.77  0.775  0.400
 04    0.250  0.160  0.190  0.160  0.190  0.160  0.650   4.30   7.05   2.35  0.775  0.400
 05    0.220  0.160  0.160  0.160  0.190  0.160  0.550   4.06   4.04   1.59  0.710  0.400
 06    0.220  0.160  0.160  0.190  0.190  0.160  0.700   3.34   3.64   1.41  0.645  0.400
 07    0.220  0.160  0.280  0.190  0.190  0.190   1.18   3.22   3.23   1.32  0.645  0.355
 08    0.220  0.160  0.190  0.190  0.310  0.130  0.800   4.54   3.12   1.23  0.580  0.355
 09    0.220  0.130  0.190  0.190  0.280  0.160   1.11   5.74   2.79   1.17  0.580  0.355
 10    0.220  0.130  0.160  0.190  0.250  0.190   1.18   5.46   2.68   1.17  0.580  0.355
 11    0.220  0.130  0.160  0.220  0.190  0.160   1.46   4.66   2.57   1.10  0.535  0.355
 12    0.220  0.130  0.160  0.220  0.190  0.160   2.05   4.30   2.24   1.10  0.535  0.355
 13    0.220  0.130  0.130  0.220  0.160  0.130   1.32   3.58   2.57   1.04  0.535  0.355
 14    0.220  0.130  0.130  0.250  0.160  0.130   1.11   2.86   2.24   1.04  0.535  0.355
 15    0.220  0.130  0.130  0.220  0.160   2.32  0.900   6.16   1.95   1.04  0.535  0.355
 16    0.250  0.130  0.130  0.250  0.130  0.340   1.87   3.58   2.35   1.04  0.490  0.310
 17    0.220  0.130  0.130  0.220  0.130  0.340  0.970   4.42   1.95  0.970  0.490  0.310
 18    0.220  0.100  0.100  0.160  0.100  0.280   2.62   5.60   1.77  0.970  0.490  0.310
 19    0.220  0.100  0.100  0.160  0.100  0.650   1.39   4.30   1.68  0.905  0.490  0.310
 20    0.220  0.100  0.100  0.160  0.090  0.550   1.69   4.30   1.59  0.905  0.490  0.310
 21    0.220  0.100  0.100  0.130  0.090  0.700   2.14   4.06   1.50  0.905  0.490  0.310
 22    0.220  0.100  0.190  0.160  0.080  0.400   2.41   6.30   1.41  0.840  0.490  0.310
 23    0.220  0.100  0.190  0.160  0.090  0.340   1.87   4.78   1.41  0.840  0.445  0.310
 24    0.220  0.100  0.130  0.190  0.080  0.280   2.23   5.04   1.23  0.840  0.445  0.310
 25    0.280  0.100  0.100  0.220  0.080  0.280   2.62   4.30   1.23  0.840  0.445  0.310
 26    0.190  0.100  0.100  0.250  0.130  0.250   4.54   4.06   1.86  0.840  0.445  0.310
 27    0.190  0.100  0.100  0.220  0.100  0.800   2.50   9.50   1.59  0.775  0.445  0.310
 28    0.190  0.100  0.100  0.190  0.550  0.850   3.94   4.42   1.68  0.710  0.445  0.310
 29    0.190         0.100  0.280  0.160  0.800   7.02   3.94   2.35  0.710  0.445  0.310
 30    0.190         0.100  0.220  0.100  0.900   5.46   4.18   1.95  0.710  0.400  0.310
 31    0.190         0.100         0.220          4.54   10.0         0.710         0.310
```

I am trying to append all of the columns together to make one column for the whole year.  However, when I try to read this in using:

```
temp <- read.table(files[i], skip = 10, fill = TRUE, nrows = 31)
temp <- temp[,2:13]
```

The blank fields simply end up at the end of each row instead of in the desired column.  For example, on day 29, February gets the value for March, March gets the value for April, etc. until December gets NA.  Basically, is there anyway to differentiate between the larger gaps and smaller gaps when reading in this table?

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a fixed width formatted file. Try this for example:

```
  read.fwf(files[i],skip=10,widths=rep(c(6,-1),13))
```

Comment: This would be my guess based on the behavior the OP is describing. +1